# Hide legend entries in a plotly figure

Tags: python, pandas, legend, plotly

The plotly docs for [legends](https://plot.ly/python/legend/) provides info on hiding legend entries:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    showlegend=False
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
)

data = [trace0, trace1]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)

py.iplot(fig, filename='hide-legend-entry')
```

However, I'm generating my plot from a `DataFrame`. So, I already have a plotly figure, and therefore don't have the liberty of setting `showlegend=False` for each trace.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
py.plot(df.iplot(kind='scatter', asFigure=True))
```

I want to hide a list of columns.

```
columns_to_hide = ['A', 'C']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set any parameters of figure before plotting like here:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# get figure property
fig = df.iplot(kind='scatter', asFigure=True)

# set showlegend property by name of trace
for trace in fig['data']: 
    if(trace['name'] != 'B'): trace['showlegend'] = False

# generate webpage
py.plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if this is a recent addition, but in current versions of plotly (4.0 and above), you can do `fig.update(layout_showlegend=False)`.

Comment: Yep, the “magic underscores” are new in 4.0. You can also do `update_layout(showlegend=False)`